# CRUD JDBC template problem with delete operation

Tags: spring-mvc, crud, spring-jdbc, jdbctemplate, http-delete

I have problem with CRUD delete operation. When i click Delete which is written in this way in jsp file `<form action="delete?Id=${medicines.id}" method="post">
  <input type="submit" value="Delete">
</form>`.

Here is my DeleteController(if I type something in doGet, then I get results from it, not blank page)

```
@WebServlet("/delete")
public class MedicinesDeleteController extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        }

    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        request.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
        int id = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("Id"));
        if(request.getUserPrincipal() != null) {
            MedicinesService query = new MedicinesService();
            query.delete(id);
            response.sendRedirect(request.getContextPath() + "/");
        } else {
            response.sendError(403);
        }
    }   
}
```

Delete function from MedicinesService(**i think this is my problem**)

```
public void delete(int id) {
    DAOFactory factory = DAOFactory.getDAOFactory();
    MedicinesDAO medicinesDao = factory.getMedicinesDAO();
    Medicines medicines = new Medicines();
    medicines.setId(id);
    medicinesDao.delete(medicines);
}
```

And  MedicinesDAOImpl

```
private final static String DELETE_MEDICINES = 
      "DELETE FROM medicines WHERE id_medicines=:id_medicines;";
@Override
public void delete(Medicines medicines) {
    SqlParameterSource namedParameter = new MapSqlParameterSource("Id", medicines.getId());
    template.update(DELETE_MEDICINES, namedParameter);
}
```

New errors

```
medicinesDao.delete(medicines); < MedicicinesService:41
template.update(DELETE_MEDICINES, namedParameter); < MedicinesDAOImpl:77
query.delete(id); <MedicinesDeleteController:31


       Type Exception Report

        Message No value supplied for the SQL parameter 'id_medicines': No value registered for key 'id_medicines'

        Description The server encountered an unexpected condition that prevented it from fulfilling the request.

        Exception

        org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: No value supplied for the SQL parameter 'id_medicines': No value registered for key 'id_medicines'
            org.springframework.jdbc.core.namedparam.NamedParameterUtils.buildValueArray(NamedParameterUtils.java:355)
            org.springframework.jdbc.core.namedparam.NamedParameterJdbcTemplate.getPreparedStatementCreator(NamedParameterJdbcTemplate.java:398)
            org.springframework.jdbc.core.namedparam.NamedParameterJdbcTemplate.getPreparedStatementCreator(NamedParameterJdbcTemplate.java:370)
            org.springframework.jdbc.core.namedparam.NamedParameterJdbcTemplate.update(NamedParameterJdbcTemplate.java:317)
            pl.firstaidkit.dao.MedicinesDAOImpl.delete(MedicinesDAOImpl.java:77)
            pl.firstaidkit.dao.MedicinesDAOImpl.delete(MedicinesDAOImpl.java:1)
            pl.firstaidkit.service.MedicinesService.delete(MedicinesService.java:41)
            pl.firstaidkit.controller.MedicinesDeleteController.doPost(MedicinesDeleteController.java:31)
            javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:660)
            javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
            org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
            pl.firstaidkit.filter.LoginFilter.doFilter(LoginFilter.java:26)
        Note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the server logs.
```

Comment: You are doing an HTTP get when you are using the anchor , which explains why doGet works() . For the doPost() to work , do a form submit with http method as post . example [here](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_form_method.asp)

Comment: I do that now i have this error
`HTTP Status 500 – Internal Server Error
Type Exception Report

Message null

Description The server encountered an unexpected condition that prevented it from fulfilling the request.

Exception

java.lang.NumberFormatException: null
 java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
 java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
 pl.firstaidkit.controller.MedicinesDeleteController.doPost(MedicinesDeleteController.java:28)`

This is 28 line 
`int id = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("Id"));`

Comment: is the parameter name `drugid` or `id` ?. please update the question with the form changes made to post

Comment: `new MapSqlParameterSource("Id", medicines.getId());` should be `new MapSqlParameterSource("id_medicines", medicines.getId());` @

Comment: I changed that so now it's `Id`. Question updated but with new errors

Comment: It's working, big thanks!

Comment: modify the method `public void delete(Medicines medicines)` as per my previous comment

Comment: I can update the answer and you can mark it closed ?

Comment: Yes we can do that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Original issue was that , this would result in an http get method call and doGet() method had no code to handle the same

```
 <a href="delete?drugid=${medicines.id}">Delete</a>
```

Second issue was with the mismatch in MapSqlParameterSource param name and place holder in query.